# How to make notification popup using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to make round notification popup with text "*User Management*", it shows messages but how can I make it round and display pop-up on top of "*User Management*" text like a notification. Is there any other way to achieve this task any help will be appreciated ?

**main.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="page-header">User Management
      <span>
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="button">
             <span class="badge">{{userList.length}}</span> Access Request
         </button>
      </span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has components 'Tooltip' and 'Popover'. I think you can use one of them.
Try the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 id="header" class="page-header" data-content="User-Managemnet-Popup" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" >User Management
      <span>
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle" type="button">
           <span class="badge">{{userList.length}}</span> Access Request
         </button>
      </span>
    </h1>
</div>
```

And activate popover in Javascript:

```
(function($){
   $('#header').popover('show');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: i am using angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Another Option could be AlertifyJs. They work pretty well:
https://github.com/kensho/ng-alertify